# ios using global navigation controller

Tags: ios

I'm trying to push something to my "current" navigation controller, but it's not going.

Why doesn't `[[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] navigationController] presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];` work?

Comment: Probably because `navigationController` is `nil`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[[window rootViewController] navigationController]` refers to the navigation controller that contains the rootViewController. Since the root controller is not inside any navigation controller, it will be always nil.

The rootViewController is probably the navigation controller itself. If that is the case you can use the code below:

```
[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES]
```

By the way, you cannot present a view modally, you should present its controller.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a nav controller? My guess is it's nil. You need to create one - the property is always present, but nil if no nav controller exists.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a MainWindow.xib file??? If so... you need to add a UINavigationController to your Palette and create a reference from your App Delegate to the UINavigationController.